# Gradle project sync failed ( Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1)

Tags: android

I want to import a new project, but I get some errors as below.

Error:

[image]

I’ve installed all the SDK platform as below.

[image]

My SDK TOOLS: 26.1.1

[image]

I’ve set all the versions to 26.

[image]

But it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Add This line to your top-level build gradle file

```
google()
jcenter()
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

Comment: I've added all the lines to build gradle file. But I get new error => Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'google()'!

Comment: Hi @ Harshil kakadiya

Thank you. I just fixed it, but aqctually I just deleted the app folder & re-imported the app. Then, it works and I don’t know why and what happened in the Android Studio (I have deleted & re-open the file over 10 times as well as troubleshot this problem with lots of the methods that I learned on the internet, but it didn’t work this afternoon). If you have the answer of why it works automatically, please tell me. Anyway, thanks!